# Getting Promise inside aggregate response

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to fetch products using aggreagte, and Later I call another api to fetch products and its count but I always get promise inside response.

How can use async wait inside exec() of aggreate, I am confused.

I have currently used pagination and getting products based on limit, but need total product count also.

Below response I am getting for total value:

totttttt Promise { 4 }

```
Product.aggregate([
      {
        
   $project: {
         
          document: "$$ROOT",

          floorAverage: {
            $floor: { $avg: "$ratings.star" }, //    //taking avg of rating arr for each prod
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $or: [
          
            obj1,
          ],
        },
      }, //now consider those prod which has avg rating
    ])
      .exec((err, aggregates) => {
        if (err) console.log("AGGREGATE ERROR", err);

        console.log("myagreg ids", aggregates);

       
          let starobj = {
            _id: aggregates,
          };
        
         //fetching products based on filter applied on these fetched avg rated products
          let newobj = {
            ...starobj,
            ...myfilterlist,
          };
       

          total = Product.find(newobj).countDocuments().exec();
        

          Product.find(newobj) 
            .populate("category", "_id name")
            .populate("subs", "_id name")
            .populate("postedBy", "_id name")
            .sort({ [sort]: order, _id: 1 }) 
            .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage) 
            .limit(perPage)
            .exec((err, products) => {
              if (err) console.log("PRODUCT AGGREGATE ERROR", err);
              // res.json(products);
              console.log("totttttt", total);
              res.json({ products, total });

            });
        }
```

I am trying to fetch products using aggreagte, and Later I call another api to fetch products and its count but I always get promise inside response.

I have currently used pagination and getting products based on limit, but need total product count also.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a promise because `aggregate.exec();` [returns a promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#Aggregate.prototype.exec()) so that is the expected behaviour. You need to `await` the call then you can store the result of the settled promise inside a variable. The same applies to your `Product.find`.

I can't comment on the success of your aggregation or database queries but based on the code you have shared if you implement these changes you should be able to achieve the desired result. Note that the `catch` block can catch any of the asynchronous call errors made with `await` but only in order. For example if the `aggregate` throws an error it jumps straight to the catch and the `Product.find` functions aren't executed:

```js
try{
    let aggregates = await Product.aggregate([ 
        {
            $project: {
                document: "$$ROOT",
                floorAverage: {
                    $floor: { $avg: "$ratings.star" }, //    //taking avg of rating arr for each prod
                },
            },
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    obj1,
                ],
            },
        }, //now consider those prod which has avg rating
    ]);
    console.log('aggregates=', aggregates);

    let starobj = {
        _id: aggregates,
    };

    //fetching products based on filter applied on these fetched avg rated products
    let newobj = {
        ...starobj,
        ...myfilterlist,
    };


    const total = await Product.find(newobj).countDocuments();
    
    const products = await Product.find(newobj)
        .populate("category", "_id name")
        .populate("subs", "_id name")
        .populate("postedBy", "_id name")
        .sort({ [sort]: order, _id: 1 })
        .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
        .limit(perPage);
    
    return res.json({ products, total });
    
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error on server' });
    //Handle err
}
```